# How do I fix the error? discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound

Tags: discord.py

Whenever I do ?+"My question" in the discord, the error comes up

```
import discord
import openai
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="?", intents=discord.Intents.all())
token = "MTA2MzkxMzQ0NTcyNjEwNTYxMA.Gzwl09.Z7z5AFSoXSzqPl9qoNy1vkSOCL7sRvvNk_2WUk"


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("\033[32m\033[1m" + "Success: Bot is connected to Discord!")


@bot.command()
async def test(ctx, *, arg):
    query = ctx.message.content
    response = openai.Completion.create(
        api_key='7bc82fafd22190d6e7e0dff98b662ab7169a7799386dbafe05de90b7f5e71335',
        model="text-davinci-003",
        prompt=query,
        temperature=0.5,
        max_tokens=60,
        top_p=0.3,
        frequency_penalty=0.5,
        presence_penalty=0.0`your text`
    )
    await ctx.channel.send(content=response['choices'][0]['text'].replace(str(query), ""))


bot.run(token)
```

discord.ext.commands.bot Ignoring exception in command None
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "hallo" is not found

Answer (score 1):

First off, you leaked both your bot token **and your OpenAI API key** so you should go reset both of them.

Next, you're saying that the error appears when you send `?+"My question"` in Discord. You don't have a command that matches this, as your error suggests. the only command you have is called `test`, so that is the only command you can use.

The error is telling you that someone tried to invoke a command that doesn't exist. If you don't care, you can create an error handler and ignore this exception. This Gist explains how to do so: https://gist.github.com/EvieePy/7822af90858ef65012ea500bcecf1612